# I need help in getting the value of a textarea in JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am making a comments system and each comments textarea gets a unique class.
My code-

```
$(".ccoomm").click(function() {
var pid = $(this).attr("id");
var tt = $("textarea ."+pid).val();
var email = $("#hidden").val();
var data = "pid=" + pid + "&text=" + tt + "&email=" + email;
$("#flash").show();
$("#flash").fadeIn(500).html('<img src="wamp.gif" /> Loading...');
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "comments.php",
    data: data,
    cache: false,
    success: function(html) {
        $(".coments"+pid).append(html);
        $("#flash").fadeOut(100);
        $("#tt").val("");
        $(".comments"+pid).slideToggle(100);
        $(this).toggleClass("active");
    }
});
```

});

I am unable to get the textarea value.... It says "undefined"

The html/php-

```
echo <li><textarea cols='20' rows='1' class='tt' id='".$comid."' placeholder='Comment..'/></textarea><input type='submit' value='Comment' id='ccoomm' class='".$comid."' /></li>";
    echo "</ul>";
```

Comment: and..? what is your question?

Comment: well, its in the question...I am unable to get the textarea value

Comment: It would be helpful if you told us what you expect your code should do, and what it is doing now.

Comment: Show us the html so that we can help you

Comment: can you show .ccoomm elements and also textarea?

Comment: Could you simplify your question? Extract what’s essential, in a simple 3 line/command example? All those vars and whatever make it really obscure, especially when the question itself seems really simple.

Comment: The website creates textareas dynamically using php. So i wont be able to give you the html, but i'll try giving you some of the php code.
The .ccoomm element is a submit button

Comment: you try to get the textarea with .$comid. class instead of .$comid. ID, you should try $("textarea #"+pid).val();

Comment: still no change, it still shows me undefined

Comment: why you cant provide us html generated by the server? how you tested the javascript code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure but are you expecting to add an `id` after `textarea` in your value selection?

Right now, it looks like you are selecting a `class`.

```
var pid = $(this).attr("id");
var tt = $("textarea ."+pid).val();
```

If you want the `id` change the second line to

```
var tt = $("textarea#"+pid).val();
```

**EDIT**

Looking at the HTML you supplied in the edit, you could change the line to

```
var tt = $("textarea.tt").val();
```

Comment: Exactly.  To reference an `id`, you need to use `#` not `.` that you have in that line of code.

Comment: Gotcha.  Did you try `var tt = $("textarea#"+pid).val();`?

Answer (score 0):

i think you put an extra space on this line (this means get all elements with that particular class that are descendant of  a textarea)

```
 var tt = $("textarea ."+pid).val();
```

should be (this means select all textarea with that particular class)

```
 var tt = $("textarea."+pid).val();
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var pid = $(this).attr("id");
```

You are getting the ID of the element that you clicked

```
var tt = $("textarea ."+pid).val();
```

You are trying to use the ID you have got as a class for selecting

Answer (score 0):

for what i can see, you would like to toggle the class of the element you've clicked.

Inside the function $.Ajax this does not refer to the element you've clicked anymore therefor inside the click function you should assign this to an variable and refer to that variable only.

```
echo <li><textarea cols='20' rows='1' class='tt' id='".$comid."' placeholder='Comment..'/></textarea><input type='submit' value='Comment' id='ccoomm' class='".$comid."' /></li>";
echo "</ul>";
```

.

```
$(".ccoomm").click(function() {
    var self = this;  
    var pid = $(self).attr("class");
    var tt = $("textarea#"+pid).val();
    var email = $("#hidden").val();
    var data = "pid=" + pid + "&text=" + tt + "&email=" + email;  

    $("#flash").show();
    $("#flash").fadeIn(500).html('<img src="wamp.gif" /> Loading...');
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "comments.php",
        data: data,
        cache: false,
        success: function(html) {
            $(".coments"+pid).append(html);
            $("#flash").fadeOut(100);
            $( tt ).val("");
            $(".comments"+pid).slideToggle(100);
            $(self).toggleClass("active");
        }
    });
});
```